# how do i run this program using attach to process?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My friend give me a project file to let me do my work, but the file he gave me. I cannot find solution file to run it when I use Visual Basic 2012 to open and view the code, there just can run with attaching to the process. I cannot run the program to see the error, can anyone help me.

[The file is here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9c7Ta0Lo2OVVjVtZzhtNmpJS0k)

Comment: [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is a Visual Studio Website Project, you'll need either Community or better version of Visual Studio, or if you can only have Express, the Web variant of VS Express. Then use File-Open-Website, point to the directory of the source code

Comment: I have a Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate version. Btw does it need to be connected to a database server?

Comment: No, the Web.config refer to LocalDB, you just need to make sure SQL Server is installed and it will use LocalDB automatically. You really need to learn the basics first instead of jumping on a complex stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an empty project and add all the files into your project.

by the way, the project that your friend gave you is written in C#, not Visual Basic.

Comment: Yes, i mean i use Visual studio to open his project. And create an empty project is create a solution(.sln) to add all the files?

Comment: Yes, just add all the files and folders